# ¿Como agregar el token csrf de django a react?

Tags: reactjs, django, djangorestframework

Este es el código de react que estoy tratando de mandar un fetch a un servidor django porque me sale crsf token missing ¿como hago para mandar o configurar el token  tengo que crear en un archivo externo? no entiendo muy bien la documentación ¿tengo que agregar la función getCookie? o agregar en el componente  que mas no sé que mas agregar por favor ya deja que publique la pregunta o tengo que agregar algo en las vistas de django.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './padNumber.css';
import CallingButton from '../callingbutton/callingbutton';



export default class PadNumber extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pressed: false,
        VALUE: 0,
        phoneNumber: [],
    };
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.HandleSubmit = this.HandleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleStateChangeLogic() {
    if (this.state.pressed) {
        console.log("Button has been pressed");
        console.log(this.state.VALUE);
        switch (true) {
            case this.state.phoneNumber.length < 8:
                // Agrega el valor al array phoneNumber
                this.setState((prevState) => {
                    const updatedPhoneNumber =  [...prevState.phoneNumber, prevState.VALUE];
                     this.props.onPhoneNumberChange(updatedPhoneNumber);
                    return {
                        phoneNumber: updatedPhoneNumber,
                    };
                });
                break;
                
            case this.state.phoneNumber.length === 8:
                fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ApiStructure/contactApi')
                .then()
           
            break;
              
            case this.state.phoneNumber.length === 0:
                console.log('prueba');
                break;

            default:
                // Cualquier otro caso
                console.log('Casos no manejados');
                break;
        }

        console.log(this.state.phoneNumber);
    }
         
}



handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(
      {
      VALUE: value,
      pressed: true,
      },
      function() {
         this.handleStateChangeLogic();
      }
    );
  }
```

Aquí es una función al submiting trato de mandar el fetch y no sé
como agregar el crsf token.

```
    HandleSubmit(){
        try {
            const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
            const phoneNumberData = {
              phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber
            };
        
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ApiStructure/contactApi', {
              method: 'POST',
              credentials: "same-origin",
              headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' // Indicamos que estamos enviando JSON
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(phoneNumberData) // Convertimos el objeto a JSON
            })
              .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.json(); // Parse the response body as JSON
              })
              .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ data, loading: false });
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                this.setState({ error, loading: false });
              });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('gatito', error);
          }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div id='Padholder'>
                <form method='POST' id='buttons' onSubmit= {this.HandleSubmit}>
                    <div className='numberButtons'>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers'  value='1' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='2' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='3' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='4' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='5' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers'  value='6' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className='numberButtons2'>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='7' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='8' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='9' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='*' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='0' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                        <input type='button' className='numbers' value='#' onClick={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <CallingButton respondingBttn='KeyboardBttn'/>
                
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```